# Use of ConcurrentDictionary in xamarin forms pcl

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, concurrentdictionary

When i tried to use `ConcurrentDictionary` by installing it from [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Concurrent/4.3.0), it says this package is not compatible with PCL profile 259:

> >
>   Error       Could not install package 'System.Collections.Concurrent 4.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

So how is concurrent access to data handled in xamarin forms pcl, I need to guard against a dictionary that is shared among multiple tasks.

Comment: It supports NetStd, you could convert your PCL to NetStandard2.0 : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/under-the-hood/net-standard/ Or use it in the Xamarin.iOS|Android application projects.

Comment: If it can be used in iOS or Android, why not forms?

Comment: It can be, but not in a `Xamarin.Forms` "PCL" project as Concurrent requires native access to threads which NetStandard 1.1(+) supplies via facades that are resolved at runtime. In a `Xamarin.Forms` NetStandard project it would work.

Comment: Ok, got it, so concurrent is platform specific. I will try to first approach, converting the pcl to netstandard project. Thanks for help!